# Shift + key not typing smaller case when caps lock is on

Tags: 20.04, keyboard

I guess the title says it all.

- pressing <kbd>a</kbd> types `a`
- pressing <kbd>Shift + a</kbd> types `A`
- (`Caps lock` on) pressing <kbd>a</kbd> types `A`
- (`Caps lock` on) pressing <kbd>Shift + a</kbd> types `A`

On windows, (`Caps lock` on) pressing <kbd>Shift + a</kbd> types `a`, but I don't know why it isn't working on Ubuntu. Is this a bug or is it a "feature"? How can I fix it?

I am using an external (bluetooth) keyboard (Dell) but I can confirm that it isn't the keyboard's problem, since the problem even occurs when I use the inbuilt keyboard.

My language is set to `English (India, with rupee)` but it doesn't work even if I change it to `English (US)`

**EDIT**: If I change it to English (UK) it works fine... How can I make it work with English (India, with rupee)?

Comment: Definitely not a feature. I guess this happens on any application? Does it happen with both shift keys?

Comment: Works just fine on my 20.04.1 Logitech PS2 English (UK) selected keyboard connected to a standard PC. What keyboard have you set in Language and Region? Please [edit] you question, not add as a comment.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Yes it is happening on every application, and with both shift keys.

Comment: Strange, if I change it to `English (UK)` it works fine... How can I make it work with `English (India, with rupee)`?

Comment: ̠₹ is created by ctrl + shift + u then type 20b9 then space bar as a constant string. This will add the rupee symbol on the English (UK) keyboard

Comment: @Vthechamp I have made a précis of my comments as an answer. If that addresses your question please consider marking it as [accepted](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) and [upvoting](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) which always helps others with the same or a similar issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT: If I change it to English (UK) it works fine... How can I make
> it work with English (India, with rupee)?

If using an English (UK) selected keyboard in Settings → Language and Region then the rupee symbol can be achieved by using the following key combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> then type <kbd>20b9</kbd> as a constant string without releasing the keys which produces the Unicode character ₹ for the Indian rupee.

There may also be an opportunity to use a keyboard shortcut for this if required (if used frequently) with US keyboard layout selected in Settings using <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> which on the Eglish(UK) will produce the Euro symbol €.

Equally, [this resource](https://www.alt-codes.net/currency-symbols) provides a simple way to copy/paste the rupee symbol.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you elaborate on the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I did a bit of research but whilst I can get the symbol in to Keyboard Shortcuts, finding a key combination which works is a problem. Désolé.